# How to center an HTML element horizontally and vertically in CSS?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have an HTML element inside another. How can I center it by two dimensions of a wrapper at one time using CSS?

I'm trying this code:

```css
.wrapper {
  heigth: 10rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.element {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">Some element</div>
</div>
```

But it centers the element only horizontally, not vertically.
Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: try justify-content:center and display:flex;  in wrapper class

Comment: @PRAKASHSOLANKI this however only aligns along the main-axis which by default is horizontally. To vertically align the items you need: `align-items: center;` the horizontally centering of the text is already done by `text-align`